# Does a platform event triggered flow run in system mode?

Tags: visual-workflow

As I understand it, normally flows are run in user mode.

However, when a flow is called from a process, the flow operates in system mode. Previously, in order to run a flow from a platform event, it was necessary to have an intermediate process to call the flow - so now that you can directly trigger a flow from a platform event, is this flow still in system mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Platform event-triggered flows are expected to run in system mode.  Tried to invoke platform event message to run flow and it got invoked successfully and was able to create a record(using flow) when there was no access to the object.

[image]

[image]
[Release Notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer20/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_fbuilder_platform_event_trigger.htm)

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

This flow does not appear to operate in user mode, since it is possible to create an object that I do not have write access for, and write to a field I do not have access to.